'require is not defined' error when I try to run bundle.mjs created by webpack
I develop an app with node.js Fastify framework (typescript, ES syntax). I use Webpack to bundle the app and to compile typescript. The app bundles successfully, but when I try to run the resulting bundle.cjs file, I get the following error:
eferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
    at Object.events (file:///home/myzader/vc-app/backend/dist/bundle.mjs:601068:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (file:///home/myzader/vc-app/backend/dist/bundle.mjs:613956:41)
    at ./node_modules/pino/lib/proto.js (file:///home/myzader/vc-app/backend/dist/bundle.mjs:612505:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (file:///home/myzader/vc-app/backend/dist/bundle.mjs:613956:41)
    at ./node_modules/pino/pino.js (file:///home/myzader/vc-app/backend/dist/bundle.mjs:613549:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (file:///home/myzader/vc-app/backend/dist/bundle.mjs:613956:41)
    at ./node_modules/fastify/lib/logger.js (file:///home/myzader/vc-app/backend/dist/bundle.mjs:607600:14)
    at __webpack_require__ (file:///home/myzader/vc-app/backend/dist/bundle.mjs:613956:41)
    at ./node_modules/fastify/lib/reply.js (file:///home/myzader/vc-app/backend/dist/bundle.mjs:608101:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (file:///home/myzader/vc-app/backend/dist/bundle.mjs:613956:41)

I tried to adjust the webpack configs. When I add some package to the externals array, it dooesn't throw the error any more, but I geet the same error for another package from dependencies. I need a help definitely, Thank you!
const config = {
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './app.ts',
  target: 'node',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.mjs'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.mjs', // Change the extension to .mjs
    library: {
      type: 'module' // Change the library type to 'module'
    },
    chunkFormat: 'module' // Change the chunk format to 'module'
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  externals: [
    nodeExternals({
      allowlist: ['canvas', 'fastify', 'avvio', 'fastq', 'reusify', '@fastify/error', 'process-warning', 'abstract-logging', 'pino', 'pino-std-serializers', 'fast-redact', 'quick-format-unescaped'] 
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.(ts|js)$/, // Handle both .ts and .js files
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /.node$/, // Apply this rule to files ending in .node
        loader: 'node-loader', // Use the node-loader for all .node files
      },
    ],
  },
  stats: {
    errorDetails: true, // Display details of errors
    colors: true, // Output in colored format, useful in console
    modules: true, // Display modules information
    reasons: true, // Display the reason about why modules are included
    warnings: true, // Display warnings
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /awilix/, // The module that includes dynamic requires
      (data) => {
        delete data.dependencies[0].critical; // Remove the critical flag from these dependencies
        return data;
      }
    ),
  ],
};


You bundle your code to ESModules, but you use require statement (in implicit way of-course...) and it's forbidden. To adjust it, make any require statement to be import instead.
Try adding(appending) this configuration to yours:
const configuration = {
    externals: [
        nodeExternals({
            modulesDir: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
            importType: (moduleName) => `import ${moduleName}`,
        }),
    ],
    experiments: { outputModule: true },
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: { type: 'module' },
        chunkFormat: 'module',
    },
};

As it seems you are only missing the externals.nodeExternals.importType key.

Thanx a lot, @Tal I applied the changes you suggest, but now I get the following error:  node bundle.js file:///home/myzader/vc-app/backend/dist/bundle.js:610370 const fastClone = __webpack_require__(/*! rfdc */ "rfdc")({ circles: false, proto: true })                                                          TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function     at ./node_modules/fastify/lib/schemas.js  ....

I am definitely loss with this , thanks @tal
